# Staging in IIS (Deployment)

Tags: iis, staging

I have three IIS server (Windows Server 2012) behind a managed load balancer, where one of these server only works as configuration server. They share the configuration with the "Shared configuration" extension.

I would like to implement something like the staging-solution,similar to azure websites. What I am trying at the moment is to swap the bindings of 2 applications. To enable web deployment I created a third site, which always points to the directory of the staging site.

To make swapping easy I added a button inour backend to swap from staging to production. The problem is that a site stops when there is a binding conflict. Because of the asynchronous nature of this solution I cannot prevent temporary conflicts at the moment.

So I tried the following solution:

1. Clear all bindings from both site,
2. CommitChanges
3. Set the bindings

It works perfect in my local scenario but not in the staging environment. The configurations are correct but I guess that there are temporary conflicts. I could add Thread.Sleep after clearing the bindings and wait for 10seconds or so, but this does not sound like a good solution for me.

Any ideas how to solve it or some better ideas for staging?